# What is the NULL environment?

Tags: r, environment

If I check the environment of the `sqrt` function, I get `NULL`:

```
> environment(sqrt)
NULL
```

On the other hand, the function `split` which is also found in the base package has the environment:

```
> environment(split)
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Why does these two functions have different environments, and what does the NULL environment mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sqrt` is a primitive function and has no R code. Per [Hadley Wickham's advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-components) page:

> **Primitive functions**
>
> There is one exception to the rule that functions have three components. Primitive functions, like `sum()`, call
>   C code directly with `.Primitive(`) and contain no R code. Therefore
>   their `formals()`, `body()`, and `environment()` are all `NULL`.